# ConvexHullMesh weirdness

Tags: bugs, computational-geometry

Consider the following:

```
pts = {{0, 1}, {1, Infinity}, {2, Infinity}, {3, Infinity}, {4, Infinity}, {5, Infinity}, {6, Infinity}, {7, 0}}
```

Now,

```
foo = ConvexHullMesh[pts]

InputForm[foo]

BoundaryMeshRegion[{{0., 1.}, {1., 0.}, {2., 0.}, {3., 0.}, {4., 0.}, 
{5., 0.}, {6., 
 0.}, {7., 0.}}, {Line[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}, 
{7, 8}, {8, 
   1}}]}, Method -> {"SeparateBoundaries" -> False}]
```

How did infinities become zeros?

Comment: I filed this as a bug. FWIW, NDSolve`FEM`ToElementMesh[pts] returns unevaluated.

Answer (score 4):

`ConvexHullMesh` uses TetGen to compute the convex hull. TetGen is an external library and can only perform computations with floating-point numbers. Hence, the wrapper for TetGen on the Mathematica side has two options: Either replacing nonnumeric data such as the symbolic `Infinity` by anything else (e.g. by `0.` as it was done here); or issueing an error (what I would prefer). As the name of the command suggests, the return value of `ConvexHullMesh` should be a mesh (a `MeshRegion`). So your desired return value cannot be represented by this data type.

Comment: It is completely clear that an error message is better than a wrong answer....